# D-link DWA-582 (AC1200) internet speed drops down in Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Tags: 16.04, drivers, wireless, internet

I have installed the DWA-582 AC1200 Wi-Fi adapter which is connected to the PCI 16x port in the motherboard.

After the installation of Ubuntu is finished, I went through `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` to ensure that all the drivers are updated. However, when I measured the internet speed in speedtest.com, comparing with my phone and laptop which are also connected to 5GHz signal, the download speed is 20~30% slower (80 Mbps > 30~60 Mbps) and the upload speed falls down rapidly (25 Mbps > 4~5 Mbps).

I have tried the method listed in the website : https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2348161

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
```

- The wifi driver for  DWA-582 is `rtl8821ae`.

It initially worked since I found the speed increasing to normal range in my phone and laptop. However, once I **reboot or install some updates, the speed falls down again.** Also, the Wi-Fi connection suddenly stops even though the connection status (wifi diagram) is 3 lines, and I have to **disconnect & re-connect** or **reboot the system** to make it connect again.

I have no idea how I can keep the connection stable and make the speed constant in normal range. **And I started to hate Ubuntu since in Windows in the same computer, it just works really fine in normal speed.**

Do you have any better ideas that I can update the driver without any fatal problems? I am currently out of ideas.

Help!